# OSX Server Reverse Proxy, Preserve IP Address

Tags: apache2, mac-osx-server, proxypass

I'm having trouble getting OSX Server's Apache service proxy to preserve the client's IP address when forwarding traffic to a Go-based server that I wrote.

Since I have OSX Server's "Websites" feature *turned off* and want to leave it that way, I followed [these instructions](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/osx-server-with-apache-reverse-proxy-problem/37843) to proxy the traffic using the Service Proxy.  The config file at `/Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy_customsites_ext.conf` contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName my.host.com:443
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   SetEnv proxy-chain-auth on
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
   RequestHeader unset Proxy early

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
       SSLEngine On
       SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.host.com/cert.pem"
       SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.host.com/privkey.pem"
       SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.host.com/chain.pem"
       SSLCipherSuite "HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES"
       SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
       SSLProxyEngine On
       SSLProxyProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
       SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
       SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_secure_transport.c>
       MSTEngine On
       MSTIdentity ${MST_IDENTITY}
       MSTCipherSuite HIGH, MEDIUM
       MSTProtocolRange TLSv1.2 TLSv1.2
       MSTProxyEngine On
       MSTProxyProtocolRange SSLv3 TLSv1.2
    </IfModule>

   ProxyPass /sub/ http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse /sub/ http://localhost:8080/

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
   RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

</VirtualHost>
```

After restarting the `com.apple.serviceproxy.plist` LaunchDaemon with `launchctl`, this works great!  Traffic to https://my.host.com/sub/ gets routed to another service listening on `:8080`

However, all of the requests show the client's IP address as `::1`.  Even the `X-Forwarded-For` header contains `::1`, and when I do `tail -f /var/log/apache2/service_proxy_access.log` all of the requests are logged like this:

```
my.host.com "my.host.com" ::1 - - [26/Mar/2018:10:13:34 -0700] "GET /sub/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8164 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
```

I'm not super familiar with Apache or OSX Server.  Is there some configuration I need to enable or fix to get the real client's IP address?  Is there some OSX Server component that I'm not thinking with?

Comment: Is your `client` the same computer that's running the app? I only ask because `::1` is the localhost/loop address in IPv6.

Comment: Is that log from your application? It's not clear what created the log entry.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8276550/799927

Comment: @shinjijai It's not the same computer.  However, further investigation has revealed that this server is behind a `socat` command, piping TCP traffic between two ports on the computer, and this might be causing all traffic to appear as coming from localhost.  :(

Comment: @MichaelHampton The log entry is in `/var/log/apache2/service_proxy_access.log` and seems to be created by the Apache service proxy.